# Non-capturing optional URL elements in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, urlconf

I'm using Django and would like to match the URLs `domain.com/w` and `domain.com/words`. I have a configuration line of the form:

```
url(r'^w(ords)?$', 'app_name.views.view_words')
```

`view_words` takes only one parameter (`request`), but it seems that Django captures the `(ords)` part of the regular expression and passes it to the view. When I remove `(ords)` from the regex and access `domain.com/w`, it works properly.

The Django documentation and similar StackOverflow questions cover how to capture optional URL parameters, but I do *not* want to capture any parameters from the URL. Is there a way to match an optional element of a URL without capturing it as a parameter?

Comment: Not a Django question at all, but a regex one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using a non-grouping parenthesis, `(?:...)`, so something like this:

```
url(r'^w(?:ords)?$', 'app_name.views.view_words')
```

See also the [documentation of python regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re-syntax)