# Django - Make parameter optional

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my urls file, I have specified the path to views -

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/userdetails', PersonalUserDetailView.as_view(), name='hello'),
    path('stores/<int:store_id>', StoreDetailView.as_view(), name='hello2'),
]
```

Howvere, I want to make the `store_id` optional. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Set default arguments in view methods

```
class StoreDetailView(...):
    def get(self, request, store_id=None):
        ...

    def post(self, request, store_id=None):
        ...
```

Also, you need to update the URL patterns a bit,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/userdetails', PersonalUserDetailView.as_view(), name='hello'),
    path('stores/<int:store_id>', StoreDetailView.as_view(), name='hello2'),
    path('stores/', StoreDetailView.as_view(), name='hello-default'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex non-capturing parenthesis, similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734358/non-capturing-optional-url-elements-in-django)

```
from django.urls import re_path


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'stores/(?:(?P<store_id>\d+)/)?$',StoreDetailView.as_view(), name="hello2"), # non-capture
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class StoreAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, store_id=None):
        if store_id is None:
           qs = Store.objects.all()
           return Reponse(.......)
        else:
           try:
              store_obj = Store.objects.get(id=store_id)
              serilized_data = StoreSerializer(store_obj).data
              return Response(....)
           except Exception as e:
              return Response(...)
```

**URLS**
`path('stores/<int:store_id>', StoreAPIView.as_view(), name='hello2')`

You can also use viewsets which is much better:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from myapps.serializers import StoreSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class StoreViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Store.objects.all()
        serializer = StoreSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Store.objects.all()
        store = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = StoreSerializer(store)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from myapp.views import StoreViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'stores', UserViewSet, basename='store')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```